# Anonymous Type, and the great unknown

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, anonymous-types

I'm attempting to explicitly define *Anonymous Type* content, but every time I attempt to access the data I receive an error: *Does not contain a definition or extension method for argument.*  Can someone explain to me, why?

```
params string[] content;
var log = content.Select(obj => new {
     Date = obj.Contains("Date"),
     Title = obj.Contains("Title"),
     Priority = obj.Contains("Priority"),
     Message = obj.Contains("Message")
});
```

Now if I attempt to to call `log.Date` that particular message would appear, why? How would I correctly do that?

Comment: I'm noticing the `foreach` in all of your examples, is there anyway to avoid the `foreach`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because log is an `IEnumerable` here. Try this instead

```
var logs = content.Select(obj => new {
     Date = obj.Contains("Date"),
     Title = obj.Contains("Title"),
     Priority = obj.Contains("Priority"),
     Message = obj.Contains("Message")
});

foreach (var log in logs)
{
    log.Date;
}
```

To avoid `foreach` implies you only need one specific item out of the `IEnumerable`, if it is the first item that you need you can use `First()` extension.

```
logs.First();
```

Otherwise, you may use in usual index like you would do for an array

Comment: So in theory to avoid the `foreach` I could do: `logs.First().Date` and `logs.First().Title`?

Comment: yep. It's more like knowing which item is needed to be accessed from the given logs collection. EG: if there are 5 items in logs , and you need the Date from 3rd item, you could do a logs[2].Date

Comment: Well, the message format passed contains those words, should I use the index rather then attempt to allocate?

Comment: yes, you could use the index too. As I said, it would depend up on which element you want to access

Answer (score 3):

Log is an enumerable:

```
foreach (var o in log) {
    bool date = o.Date;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`log` is `IEnumerable` of anonymous type in this case. So `log` it self doesn't have `Date` member, but item in `log` has :

```
var dateOfFirstItem = log.First().Date;
```

You can do something like this if you're sure there is always at least one item in `content` :

```
var log = content.Select(obj => new {
     Date = obj.Contains("Date"),
     Title = obj.Contains("Title"),
     Priority = obj.Contains("Priority"),
     Message = obj.Contains("Message")
}).First();
var date = log.Date
var title = log.Title
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Select clause returns IEnumerable so if you are sure that the selection of content object will return only one element, you can use SingleOrDefault() function as follow:

```
var log = content.Select(obj => new {
     Date = obj.Contains("Date"),
     Title = obj.Contains("Title"),
     Priority = obj.Contains("Priority"),
     Message = obj.Contains("Message")
}).SingleOrDefault();
```